# Terraform can't deploy API Gateway changes to one stage out of many?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, terraform

Using this code:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "example_deployment" {
  depends_on = [
    "aws_api_gateway_method.example_api_method",
    "aws_api_gateway_integration.example_api_method_integration"
  ]
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example_api.id}"
  stage_name = "${var.stage_name}"
}
```

I can deploy API Gateway changes to whatever stage I specify. However, this will override any existing stages. That is, if I first deploy to a stage called 'dev', then deploy to 'prod', it will erase 'dev'.

How can I achieve multi-stage deployments? So that I can first deploy to dev or staging, and if it all looks good, then deploy to the prod stage.

Comment: Terraform doesn't really handle the API Gateway release model particularly well although I think there's an issue for trying to handle things like this and ECS task definitions on the AWS provider repo. Instead you're better off creating separate API Gateway resources for each stage and linking things that way. To save copy pasting stuff you'll probably want to wrap the resources in a module and then configure the name/stage when you source it.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR thanks for the reply. In the end, that's exactly what we did - separate folders/state files per stage, and then using modules to keep it DRY.

Comment: You might want to consider self answering your question with a minimal example of what you did to achieve this for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, we ended up taking a different tack. Based on articles like [this](https://blog.gruntwork.io/how-to-manage-terraform-state-28f5697e68fa) and [this](https://charity.wtf/2016/03/30/terraform-vpc-and-why-you-want-a-tfstate-file-per-env/), we split our terraform into folders per stage. So if you want to deploy dev, you run terraform inside the dev folder. To avoid code duplication, you use [modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/create.html). It seems to be working well, and allows us to deploy different versions of the API.